# Executing DB Update on Startup in ASP .Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor-pages

I am working on an application that should take data from one server and put the data into my database. I am currently struggling to update the database on startups.

I tried several approaches like creating an action which is calling a model which updates the database (with no luck), I tried to research if there is a way to do it in Startup class, but again with no luck.

I have these methods for now

**TfsMethods.cs** (Models class)

```
    public TfsMethods(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void UpdateDbBranches()
    {
        var branches = GetAllBranches();
        var dbBranches = _db.Branches;
        foreach (var branch in branches)
        {
            if (dbBranches.Where(x => x.BranchName == branch.BranchName) == null)
            {
                _db.Add(branch);
            }
        }
    }
```

where `_db` is `ApplicationDbContext`  and GetAllBranches() is a method which gets data from one server and I want to put these into my DB.

**BranchController.cs** (Controller class)

```
public IActionResult UpdateDbBranches()
    {
        TfsMethods tfs = new TfsMethods( _db );
        try
        {
            tfs.UpdateDbBranches();
            return Ok();
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            return Problem( e.ToString() );
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that I don't know what to call it on startups, even on razor page or Startup.cs

Is this somehow possible or is there any implementation that could help me with this issue?

Comment: take a look at background services
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: How do you want to actually trigger this? Normally a data transfer is triggered on a schedule or on some other specific trigger. It is very unusual to trigger a data transfer on a web application startup. How often should this data actually be transferred? It seems like you are trying to use a web application to do data integration.

Comment: Descriptions like "with no luck" imply that you haven't analysed how it actually failed. You'll need to do that to be able to describe in what way it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several useful answers already available at:
[Application startup code in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047229/application-startup-code-in-asp-net-core)

However, you should first consider if you really want to do this on startup or on a schedule. See Quartz.net for example: https://www.infoworld.com/article/3529418/how-to-schedule-jobs-using-quartznet-in-aspnet-core.html

If you're trying to do so-called Database Seeding, these links (and links in those discussions) may be useful to you:

- https://github.com/Homely/Homely.AspNetCore.Hosting.CoreApp/issues/11
- https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10137
- https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/issues/638